# Can one efficiently LEFT OUTER JOIN a subset of the left table's rows in Postgres?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
table_1                  table_2
id_a    name             id_a    id_b
1       c                1       1
2       a                1       2
3       b                2       1
                         2       2
```

Now consider the following LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 USING (id_a)

id_a    name  id_b  
1       c     1
1       c     2
2       a     1
2       a     2
3       b
```

Now imagine that 'FROM table_1' is actually a complex sub-query, like:

```
SELECT * FROM huge_table WHERE expensive_conditions_producing_three_rows
```

Is it possible to write a query that only joins against the left row with the minimum name, without re-running the sub-query entirely?  You can assume that you have some control over the sub-query, i.e. you could add an ORDER BY if necessary.

In other words, the end result should look like this:

```
id_a    name  id_b
1       c
2       a     1
2       a     2
3       b
```

I considered using SELECT INTO to place the sub-query results in a temporary table.  Then it wouldn't be a problem to compute the minimum for use in a JOIN ON condition.  But I'd prefer to avoid this unless it's the only solution.

Edit: I'll wait a couple of days and then accept the best solution, regardless of PG version.  One that works in PG 8.3 and earlier would be greatly appreciated, though.

Comment: tried to use these http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html   ?

Comment: I didn't specify a version, since I wanted to keep the question useful for others doing similar things.  But I would personally love to see something that works in PG 8.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [CTE (common table expression)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) for that (available for PostgreSQL 8.4 or later):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id_a, name
    FROM   table_1
    WHERE  expensive_conditions_producing_three_rows
    )
SELECT c.id_a, c.name, t2.id_b
FROM   cte c
LEFT   JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id_a = c.id_a
                     AND t2.name = (SELECT min(name) FROM cte)
```

Comment: Don't know about PostgreSQL, but in SQL Server this would probably fail the *‘without re-running the sub-query entirely’* part of the question, because `cte` would be evaluated twice.

Comment: @AndriyM: In PostgreSQL it certainly doesn't. (Just tested to verify, but that was a waste of my time.) The **whole point** of a CTE is to use the resulting values without rerunning the query. Now, I don't know about SQL server, but I strongly doubt it is dumb enough to do the opposite.

Comment: In SQL Server, CTEs are more akin to views than to temporary tables. I guess, if you referenced a view more than once in the same query, you'd probably be prepared for the fact that the view could be evaluated more than once as well. So it is with CTEs (in SQL Server). The optimiser *might* eliminate some re-evaluations, but that is far from being guaranteed.

Comment: @AndriyM: Thanks for the insight. I haven't studied the source code of PostgreSQL's implementation. But from what I have seen, CTEs are treated as temporary tables exclusively visible to the query. If you reference a CTE later in your query, the planner performs a *CTE scan* on the results of the initial query.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) (available from PostgreSQL 8.4):

```
SELECT *
FROM
      ( SELECT *
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) AS RowNum
        FROM table_1
      ) AS a
  LEFT JOIN
      table_2 AS b
    ON 
       (join condition)
    AND
       a.RowNum = 1
```